# Why is my DNS not propagating?

Tags: domain-name-system

Around a month ago, in anticipation of the demise of Google Domains, I migrated to porkbun.

The moment I did this, Google rug-pulled me and deleted all records of my domain from their side despite my domain's NS records still pointing to Google. Guh! (Note to self: copy DNS first, move domain second)

Anyways, after copying the DNS records over the porkbun, service was restored... Or was it?

The domain loads fine for me, but I started receiving emails saying that they couldn't.

This was a month ago.

It seems that many major DNS providers (Google, Cloudflare) have not picked up the new domain.

Here's some diagnostics I ran. The domain is **bbss.dev**

​

```
% dig @curitiba.ns.porkbun.com bbss.dev +short # Query A directly from registrar - correct!
155.138.128.203
% dig @1.1.1.1 bbss.dev +short # Query A from Cloudflare, no reply
% dig @8.8.8.8 bbss.dev +short # Query A from Google, no reply
% dig @8.8.8.8 bbss.dev NS +short # Query NS from Google, no reply
% dig @curitiba.ns.porkbun.com bbss.dev NS +short # Query NS from registrar, correct!
curitiba.ns.porkbun.com.
fortaleza.ns.porkbun.com.
maceio.ns.porkbun.com.
salvador.ns.porkbun.com.
```

Any advice is welcome, I'm at the end of my wits.

Comment: It's not helpful, I'm pretty sure, but your "responsible mail addr" field in your SOA record contains `dns.cloudflare.com` ... might want to change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(DNS is not propagating because DNS does not have a propagating architecture, but a cached one.)*

### Why was the DNS for `bbss.dev` not cached?

The domain had DNSSEC enabled, but the zone was not signed.

### Your two options

1. Disable DNSSEC for `bbss.dev` at the registrar (typically on their web management).
2. Sign the `bbss.dev` zone with the key (tag `58006` algorithm `RSA/SHA-256`).

### Debugging procedures used

There was a `DS` record at the parent zone (`.dev`).

```
$ dig bbss.dev DS +short
58006 8 2 4AE163D6F53B54DDD8BECDADAC2B59BCC9454E615D64908E74550105 8D32CB84
```

The `DNSKEY` & `RRSIG` records were missing from the authoritative server(s).

```
$ dig bbss.dev DNSKEY @curitiba.ns.porkbun.com +dnssec +short

$ dig bbss.dev @curitiba.ns.porkbun.com +dnssec +short
155.138.128.203
```

Whereas it should have shown (as it does now that it is fixed using a new key tag `2371` algorithm `ECDSAP256SHA256`):

```
$ dig bbss.dev DS +short
2371 13 2 F26B97569A01286E330928EADBE30FB136F34C99E8837554683C14A4 9DCDB66A

$ dig bbss.dev DNSKEY @curitiba.ns.porkbun.com +dnssec +short
257 3 13 mdsswUyr3DPW132mOi8V9xESWE8jTo0dxCjjnopKl+GqJxpVXckHAeF+ KkxLbxILfDLUT0rAK9iUzy1L53eKGQ==
256 3 13 oJMRESz5E4gYzS/q6XDrvU1qMPYIjCWzJaOau8XNEZeqCYKD5ar0IRd8 KqXXFJkqmVfRvMGPmM1x8fGAa2XhSA==
DNSKEY 13 2 3600 20231003155124 20230803155124 2371 bbss.dev. J41q4bxPzWxQNBCjOXL3KaGLdQeM1XG7rc4jB0QUKVEEQ7kBLAdPNzDy odRDJVMVK0X5T6UHonSQNrDcuWdYxQ==

$ dig bbss.dev @curitiba.ns.porkbun.com +dnssec +short
155.138.128.203
A 13 2 600 20230805171103 20230803151103 34505 bbss.dev. oVo2BARrTNRk0uMw9pbEwCYjBSVP7Pt+HixVEg7McdJsISax/DIiQ4Sq GzYLG4azFTNea/HW6KFWN9477c68zg==
```

Both the [Verisign DNSSEC Analyzer](https://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/bbss.dev) & the [DNSViz](https://dnsviz.net/d/bbss.dev/dnssec/) showed the same problem:

> [image: DNSSEC Analyzer results]

> [image: DNSViz diagram for bbss.dev]

Comment: I actually needed to _enable_ DNSSEC on my registrar.

Comment: It was enabled, but with an old `DS` record. If it was disabled, the bogus RRSIG and DNSKEY records would not have been a problem.